# Use reduce to get certain values in many arrays nested in a larger array nested in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, javascript-objects, nested-loops

I am trying to return two values from each nested array in a larger array which are all inside of an object. I need to return two values inside of *pages* (array) for EACH *category* (parent array) on dynamically rendered data(object).

```
Sample JSON: 
"categories": [
      {
        "rank": 14,
        "title": "Product",
        "pages": [
          {
            "audience": 16,
            "title": "X",
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
          },
          {
            "audience": 19510000,
            "title": "Y",
            "url": "https://www.yahoo.com"
          },  
        ]
      },
      {
        "rank": 23,
        "title": "Media",
        "pages": [
          {
            "audience": 168,
            "title": "A",
            "url": "https://www.google.com"
          },
          {
            "audience": 17120000,
            "title": "B",
            "url": "https://www.CNN.com"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "rank": 123,
        "title": "Accounting",
        "pages": [
          {
            "audience": 16,
            "title": "C",
            "url": "https://www.wave"
          },
          {
            "audience": 17680000,
            "title": "D",
            "url": "https://www.facebook.com"
          }
        ]
      }
```

I have been able to use map to get values I need out of the categories array like so (this gets back all data needed from categories:

```
 serialize(data){
    return data.categories.map( obj => {
      return {
        rank: obj.rank,
        title: obj.title
      }
    })
  }
```

Output I get for above: array of objects containing the values needed from categories array after calling above function on the JSON data:

```
[
 {
  "rank": 14
  "title": "Product"
  }
 {
  "rank": 23
  "title": "Media"
  } 
 {
  "rank": 123
  "title": "Accounting"
  }
]
```

I am unclear on how to go a level deeper to return the pages array for each category. I want to return the data in a similar fashion as shown above:

```
serialize(data){
        return data.categories[0].pages.map( obj => {
          return {
            url: obj.url,
            text: obj.text
          }
        })
      }
```

With above, I obviously only get back the *first* pages array containing objects for each key value pair of title url, and I need every one for all categories (I get back about 50). I know reduce may work but having trouble implementing it. I want the url and title for each page array for each category.

Expected output for pages - array of Objects containing page values needed:

```
[
 { 
  "title": "A",
  "url": "https://www.google.com"
  },  
  {
  "title": "B",
  "url": "https://www.facebook.com"
  },
  {
   "title": "A",
  "url": "https://www.CNN.com"
   }
]
```

Comment: Please show an expected input/output to clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Call `.map()` inside the other `.map()`?

Comment: Please use valid JSON for your input and output examples instead of some pseudo markup.